# How can i remove extra black space in a movie clip in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, flash-cc

In `flash Cs6` or `CC` when i convert a image into movie clip no matter what kind of image is that it will take e `square shape` with extra space.

lets say a pyramid shape image which has two side, narrow side and wide side if i convert it into a movie clip its always taking a `square shape` with extra space in both side. `(Narrow side)`

its creating a big problem in my game where i use `(hitTestObject)`. Is there any way to solve it.

Comment: There is a ton of information on this. Google your query. I would search "true hitTest as3" or "pixel perfect as3 hitTest".

Comment: [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pixel-level-collision-detection--active-10862) is a TutsPlus tutorial on pixel level detection of bitmaps.

Comment: Did you mean **blank** space or **black** space. If _"blank"_ you need to google for **AS3 pixel perfect collision detection**. Or else if _"black"_ then chances are you're not drawing a transparent bitmap, show that code.